# product link type_not_exists when trying to update associated products with api

Tags: api, magento-1, products, grouped-products

I am trying to programmatically update the position value for simple products within a grouped product.  I am trying to use the product_link_api with Mag 1.9.01

```
$api = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link_api');
$api->update(...);
```

The function definition start looks like this:

```
public function update($type, $productId, $linkedProductId, $data = array(), $identifierType = null)
{...}
```

Now this seems to be very odd function in that you can specify whether the $productId is the magento id or the SKU by using the $identifierType parameter. However the $linkedProductId seems to want a SKU:

```
...
    $idBySku = $product->getIdBySku($linkedProductId);
    if ($idBySku) {
        $linkedProductId = $idBySku;
    }
...
```

Not sure how it know whether it is not but that is by-the-by.  What I am having trouble with is that no matter what I pass in as the $type I get a message like:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Api_Exception' with message 'type_not_exists' in ......\app\code\core\Mage\Api\Model\Resource\Abstract.php on line 103
```

I have looked into the catalog_product_link_type table and have:

```
1 relation
3 super
4 up_sell
5 cross_sell
```

Looking into the catalog_Product_link  table I have seen that the "associated" products I want to modify are related using link type 3 "super".   However, passing "super" summons the error, passing "3" causes the error.  I have seen that one should pass "grouped" in so I tried that, even thought it made no sense to me given that it wasn't in the link type table.  Failed too.

Any pointers on this? Thanks

Comment: [Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductLink/catalog_product_link.update.html) and [code](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.0.1/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Link/Api.php#L41) clearly depict the allowed values. The _grouped_ type should be fine. If that failed, it likely failed due to another subsequent error.

Comment: Cheers mam08ixo. I was looking at the documention but as "grouped" failed I attempted to nose into the db structure. I confess I hadn't spotted the $_typeMap  array though